# How to improve precision while measuring using OpenCV python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, measure, perspectivecamera

I have been trying to measure window panes using a reference object (a 3x5 checkerboard) in OpenCV python, but my measurements are off from the real value by about 5-10%. Is there a way to improve the precision of the measurements?

**My current approach:**

1. Calibrate the camera using the images of reference objects from different angles
2. Find an undistorted image using a `cv2.undistort()`
3. Finding corners of the reference object using `findChessboardCorners()`
4. Create an array of top-view points
5. Use `findHomography()` and `warpPerspective()` to convert the original image to top-view
6. Choose four points that are most likely the edges of the windowpane
7. Find the edge pixels based on the 4 corners
8. Using the corners of the reference object to find the approximate length of each square
9. Use edge pixels to compute the relative length of the windowpane
10. Use the actual length and found the length of reference squares to find the ratio and use that ratio to find the actual length of the window pane

I am attaching the reference object used and the image here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
[window_pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgWCv.jpg)

The original measurements of the window pane are 6x10 inches.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import math
import os
import base64
import json
from sys import argv
import sys
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

def get_refrence_corners(image):
    cornersList = []
    # resized = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (5,3),None)
    print(ret)
    # If found
    if ret == True:
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        for x in range(len(corners2)):
            cornersList.append(corners2[x][0])
    return cornersList

def get_corners(img_resized, sensitivity):
    cornersList = []
    imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(imgGrey, sensitivity, 0.01, 60)
    corners = np.float32(corners)
    for corner in corners:
        x, y = corner.ravel()
        if x.item() > 325 or x.item() < 55 or y.item() > 1515 or y.item() < 1335:
            cornersList.append((x.item(),y.item()))
    return cornersList

def get_dist_two_points(point1, point2):
    distX = abs(point1[0] - point2[0])
    distY = abs(point1[1] - point2[1])
    dist = math.sqrt(distX**2 + distY**2)
    return dist

def get_edges_pixels(chosen, edge_pixels) :
    biggest_sum = chosen[0][0] + chosen[0][1]
    smallest_sum = chosen[0][0] + chosen[0][1]
    smallest_corner = 0
    biggest_corner = 0
    for edge in range(len(chosen)):
        if (chosen[edge][0] + chosen[edge][1]) > biggest_sum:
            biggest_sum = (chosen[edge][0] + chosen[edge][1])
            biggest_corner = edge
        elif (chosen[edge][0] + chosen[edge][1]) < smallest_sum:
            smallest_sum = (chosen[edge][0] + chosen[edge][1])
            smallest_corner = edge
    for corner in range(len(chosen)):
        if corner != smallest_corner and corner != biggest_corner:
            dist = get_dist_two_points(chosen[corner], chosen[smallest_corner])
            edge_pixels.append(dist)
            dist = get_dist_two_points(chosen[corner], chosen[biggest_corner])
            edge_pixels.append(dist)
    return edge_pixels

def get_relative_length(edge_pixels, refLength):
    ref = (refLength[1] + refLength[0]) / 2
    average_x = (edge_pixels[0] + edge_pixels[3]) / 2
    average_y = (edge_pixels[1] + edge_pixels[2]) / 2
    x = (average_x / ref)
    y = (average_y / ref)
    length = [x * 17/32, y * 17/32]
    return length

def get_refrence_length(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (5,3),None)
    if ret == True:
        avg_horz = 0
        avg_virt = 0
        edges_horz = 0
        edges_virt = 0
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        for x in range (14):
            if ((x + 1) % 5) != 0 :
                avg_virt += get_dist_two_points(corners2[x][0], corners2[x+1][0])
                edges_virt += 1
            # if the point is in the row skip the comparison as there is no points on the left
            if (x + 5) <= 14 :
                avg_horz += get_dist_two_points(corners2[x][0], corners2[x+5][0])
                edges_horz += 1

    return [avg_horz / edges_horz, avg_virt / edges_virt]

imgpoints = np.load('/content/imgpoints.pkl', allow_pickle=True)
objpoints = np.load('/content/objpoints.pkl', allow_pickle=True)

path = '/content/IMG_4854.JPG'
image = cv2.imread(path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

img = cv2.imread('/content/IMG_4854.JPG')
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))

# undistort
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

# crop the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('calibresult.png',dst)


finalImage = cv2.imread('/content/calibresult.png')
grayFinal = cv2.cvtColor(finalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

reference_corners = get_refrence_corners(finalImage)
reference_corners = np.float32(reference_corners)

sorted_reference_points = np.array(sorted(reference_corners,key = lambda x: x[1]))

top_view_points = np.float32([(200, 1380), (245, 1380), (290, 1380), (335, 1380), (380, 1380),
                            (200, 1425), (245, 1425), (290, 1425), (335, 1425), (380, 1425),
                            (200, 1470), (245, 1470), (290, 1470), (335, 1470), (380, 1470)])

sorted_top_view_points = top_view_points[top_view_points[:,0].argsort()]
print(sorted_top_view_points)

M, mask = cv2.findHomography(sorted_reference_points, top_view_points, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)


dst = cv2.warpPerspective(finalImage,M,(1080,1920), flags = cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = [0, 0, 0, 0])

dst_path = '/content/dst.jpeg'
cv2.imwrite(dst_path, dst)

corners = get_corners(dst, 100)
corners = np.float32(corners)

chosen_corners = [(90, 560), (700, 570), (150, 1510), (632, 1510)]

chosen_corners = np.int0(chosen_corners)

edge_pixels = []
edge_pixels = get_edges_pixels(chosen_corners, edge_pixels)

reference_length = get_refrence_length(dst)

measurement = get_relative_length(edge_pixels, reference_length)
```

Comment: Without any reproducible sample code, it will be impossible to know whether there's an error in your approach, or an error in your code.

Comment: I added the code which you can use to replicate the results